# Reverse of array_search() that looks for the key instead of the value

Tags: php, arrays, function

PHP's `array_search()` does this:

> Searches the array for a given **value** and returns the corresponding **key** if successful

I would like a function that does the exact opposite, that is, searches the array for a given **key** and returns the corresponding **value** if successful.

Is this available at all in PHP 5? If not, what solution would you suggest?

Comment: why don't you just try accessing the array with the key?

Comment: Maybe he wants to say with a multi dimensional array?

Comment: array_search() searches for a given value and returns the index/key, which is not how the OP worded it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use square bracket syntax, as follows:

```
$arr = array("key" => "value");
$v = $arr["key"]; // returns "value"
```

Answer (score 11):

I am confused. Would `$array[$key]` not work?

Answer (score 2):

To comply with PHP tradition

```
function array_search_reverse($needle, $haystack){
return $haystack[$needle];
}
```